# How to access selected item from dropdown in asp.net mvc3

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

i am using asp.net mvc3 and i populate a create view using following model

**Model**

```
public class CategoryModel
{
    public  int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public  string URL { get; set; }
    public  string Description { get; set; }
    public  string Logo { get; set; }
    public  bool IsActive { get; set; }
    public  bool isPopular { get; set; }
    public IList<Category> Parentcategories { get; set; }

}
```

In my create View i populate like this

**View**

```
 <div class="editor-field">
        @Html.DropDownList("parentcategories", new SelectList(Model.Parentcategories.Select(c => c.Name), Model.Parentcategories.Select(c => c.Name)))
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Parentcategories)
    </div>
```

now how can i access the selected item in my controller method

**Method**

```
 [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Create( CategoryModel model , HttpPostedFileBase file)
    {
     // 
    }
```

thanks,
Ahsan

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
public ActionResult Create(string parentcategories, CategoryModel model , HttpPostedFileBase file)
```

`parentcategories` will contain selected `option` value.

Comment: is there any way to do it using `CategoryModel` ?

Comment: @Smartboy Yes, use property and then write `DropDownListFor` for this property.

Answer (score 1):

As **Smartboy** already mentioned, you should use DropDownListFor:
1. append your model with `public  int ParentCategoryId { get; set; }` field.
2. instead of using @Html.DropDownList use:
`@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.ParentCategoryId, new SelectList(...))`
3. the server side can stay the same:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Create(CategoryModel model)
{
   // 
}
```

where `model.ParentCategoryId` will have selected item value.
Also note that you can first set selected item value for your view:

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
  var model = CategoryModel();
  ...
  model.ParentCategoryId = some_selected_value;
  return View(model);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**Details:** You can access it directly from your model.

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Create( CategoryModel model , HttpPostedFileBase file)
{
      var selectedCategory = model.parentcategories;  // something like that
}
```